# C# and ObjectInputStream in Java via Socket!

Tags: sockets

I hava a socket server is written in Java and the client is written in C#.

If I use the InputStream in a socket server, I can get the request from the Client. My code as below:

> InputStream myIN = sock.getInputStream();
> byte[] b  = new byte[10];
> int revByte = myIN.read(b);

but if I use the ObjectInputStream in the socket server, I can not receive any request from the Client.
The exception is: "**java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header**"
My code as below:

> in = new ObjectInputStream( sock.getInputStream() );
> Object value = in.readObject();

So, my question is: can C# client work with ObjectInputStream in Java via socket?

Any helping will be appreciate.
Thanks so much, 
Dan

Answer (score 3):

ObjectInputStream expects a data stream containing serialized representations of java objects... theoretically c# could encode it's objects in java's serialization format, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: Thanks jspcal. Do you have a sample to encode C# objects in Java's serialization? or any links about it. Please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

jspcal is right: Maybe with these classes?

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/java-and-c-client-server-socket-programming/

Java Server

```
try
{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1800);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Client Accepted");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()),true);
    wr.println("Welcome to Socket Programming");
}
catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e); }
```

C# Client:

```
try
{
    TcpClient tc = new TcpClient("server",1800);// in the place of server, enter your java server's hostname or Ip
    Console.WriteLine("Server invoked");
    NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    sw.WriteLine("My name is Pramod.A");
    sw.Flush();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
}
catch(Exception e){ Console.WriteLine(e); }
```